# Running python script anywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe, pythonanywhere

I have developed some scripts which I need to share with colleagues who does not have python nor have underlying distributions to run it. How to automatically configure environment and more importantly run the script without even python installed?

I saw some solutions on SO like py2exe. Not sure that it’s the best option. Docker is also not possible since in my case I need something what can work simply by running `python3 path/to/program`

Comment: Use docker to distribute the program

Comment: py2exe seems to be a good way to distribute python script.

Comment: Would you be connected to the internet?

Comment: @technazi this is under question. Ideally everything should be inside the app including all dependencies

Answer (score 2):

You can use online coding platforms like [`repl.it`](https://repl.it/) to run scripts from the browser so u don't want to install python locally.

Comment: Thanks! Will explore this one for sure, however, script has input output functionality and there may be issue with one of the APIs I use.

Comment: Your welcome, I Think there will be no problem with input and output because i saw lot of them using repl.it to create GUI but i am not sure about APIs

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complexity of the script.

If it is doing complex things that it needs to be run on your computer for, like file input & output, then [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) is probably the way:

```
pip isntall
pyinstaller -- onefile script.py
```

---

If it is just a short script, then [Repl.It](https://repl.it/languages/python3) is a great way to save and share scripts that can be viewed and run right in the browser. It supports installing pip packages and environments. It even has a feature where you can host a terminal app as a website: [repl.run](https://repl.it/talk/announcements/BetaExplorers-Announcing-replrun-publish-your-terminal-apps-as-websites/)

Comment: Yeah. It’s sort of complex since it uses several external APIs for which I have only local access authorised meaning I cannot use it on the server

Comment: Yeah so go for Pyinstaller then! :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into a exe file using  `pyinstaller`
Following are the steps:

```
1. Open cmd on the folder in which you stored your py file

2.type it on the cmd
```

```
pyinstaller -- onefile filename.py
```

If you don't have pyinstaller module then install it using

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Comment: Any idea how to add dependencies? I’m new to packing all the stuff since I’m an analyst:)

Answer (score 0):

I am using `PyInstaller` to create a complete standalone executables, that does not depend on a machine having `python` interpreter. Here is a complete guide: https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/